# Find the slope of a tangent to a curve when $x = 4$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am being asked to find the slope of a tangent to a curve when $x=4$.

The equation I have is $f(x) = 4x^3 - 5x + 2\sqrt{x}$

I'm a beginner and I must say that I'm having a hard time with this. I have read [this previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460989/slope-of-line-tangent-to-a-curve-at-a-given-point-using-first-principles) but I'm not sure how to apply it to my problem.

Thanks

Comment: The slope of the tangent to a (differentiable) curve at a certain point $x=x_0$ is $f'(x_0)$, the derivative of the function at that point.

Comment: @user142050 That previous post isn't going to help a whole lot. Do you know how to take the derivative of your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=4x^3-5x+2\sqrt{x}\\
\implies f^\prime(x)=12x^2-5+x^{-1/2}\\
\implies f^\prime(4)=12\times16-5+\dfrac{1}{2}=187.5\\
\implies y-f(4)=f^\prime(4)(x-4)
\text{Now, }f(4)=4\times64-5\times4+2\times2=240\\
\implies \text{Tangent line: }y-240=187.5(x-4)$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$f(x) = 4x^3 - 5x + 2\sqrt{x} = 4x^3 - 5x + 2x^{1/2}.$$

What does $f'(x)$ represent, and in particular $f'(4)$? Can you compute it?

Answer (score 0):

The slope tangent to $f$ at $x = 4 $ is the derivative of $f$ evaluated at $x = 4 $: hence using power rule, we have

$$f'(x) = 12 x^2 - 5 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} } $$

$$ \therefore f'(4) = 12(4)^2 - 5 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} = 192 - 5 + \frac{1}{2} = 187 + \frac{1}{2} = 187.5
$$