# Finding the slope of a curve with a given point

Tags: derivatives

I am just stuck and cannot see how to solve this question, I've have a complete mind blank.

Find the slope of the curve 
$$y= 2x^3 − 8x^2+1$$

at the point $(2, -15).$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460989/slope-of-line-tangent-to-a-curve-at-a-given-point-using-first-principles

Comment: Do you know how to compute the derivative of a function? Do you know what it represents?

Comment: Nope I have completely forgotten everything sadly.

Comment: and yeah that related link helps but I dont know what to do with the +1 at the end

Comment: The +1 is a constant and it disappears, if you differentiate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, we have the equation of the curve $$y=2x^3-8x^2+1$$

the slope of the tangent at general point $(x, y)$ of the curve is given as $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(2x^3-8x^2+1)$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=6x^2-16x$$ Hence, the slope of (the tangent) at the given point $(2, -15)$ is given as $$\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\right]_{(2, -15)}=6(2)^2-16(2)=24-32=-8$$

Answer (score 0):

Tthe slope at the point $x$ is given by: $$y'(x)=6x^2-16x$$ Here you can substitute $x=2$.

Answer (score 0):

The slope of $ y =2x^3-8x^2+1$ can be found by evaluating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $(2, -15)$.

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = 6x^2-16x$$
When $x=2$, $\text{Slope at (2, -15)} = \frac{dy}{dx} = 6(2^2)-16(2) = ?$

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$

Can you do the rest?

Comment: I'd highly appreciate it if you could put the whole solution up as I need it for revision. but nonetheless thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: Are you sure you can't find $(6 \times 2^2) - (16 \times 2)$? How old are you?

Comment: I thought there was more too it thats all, thanks though

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d}{dx}$ is a linear operator, so you can apply it to each $x^n$ term in the individual summands, also:

$$\frac{d}{dx}x^n = nx^{n-1}$$

hence:

$$
\begin{align}
y&= 2x^3 − 8x^2+1\\
 &= 2x^3 − 8x^2+1\color{green}{x^0}\\
\frac{d}{dx}y &= \frac{d}{dx}\left(2x^3 − 8x^2+1\color{green}{x^0}\right)\\ &=2\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^3\right) − 8\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\right)+1\color{green}{\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^0\right)}\\
&=2\cdot 3x^2  − 8\cdot 2x\color{green}{^1}+1\color{green}{\cdot 0x^{-1}}\\
&=6x^2-16x\\
\end{align}$$

The parts in green are usually not written out like that. There are usually rules like "*a constant summand (1 in this case) becomes 0*". But the general rule actually holds for $n=0$, so why bother coming up with additional rules? Math is complicated enough already.

Now insert the value 2:

$$6\cdot2^2-16\cdot 2= 24-32=-8\\$$

What's also good to know is if the point they are asking for is actually part of the function:

$$2\cdot2^3 − 8\cdot2^2+1 = 2\cdot8 - 8\cdot4+1 = 16-32+1=-15\\$$

Great, this wasn't a trick question.
The slope is $-8$ at that point.