# Critiquing the notion of a tangent as a line that "just touches" a curve.

Tags: definition, circles, curves, tangent-line

The most common answer to this question "What is tangent to any curve?" is as follows:

> "Tangent to a plane curve at a given point is the straight line that
> "just touches" the curve at that point. "

But this definition have **two problems**.

**First** is what do you mean by "just touches"? How can I know if a line "just  touches"  a curve or not?

For example: How do you know that the red line in the following image "just touches" the curve while green line doesn't?

[image]

**Second** problem is that this definition doesn't generalize to the "straight-line curve" .

A tangent to a straight line is the straight line itself. But this can't be possible under the "just touches" definition. (This is just what I think, if you think my reasoning is incorrect then please correct me.)

So what is tangent to any curve?  **And also** if my objections are correct then why is this definition so famous?

---

Comment: limit of secants?

Comment: There are probably many ways to answer this, depending on what the exact question is. Do you know one-variable calculus?

Comment: It's the line that best approximates the curve at that point.

Comment: @ElliotG I don't know calculus. Actually this question came to me when I started to learn differentiation!

Comment: This is not a definition, but rather the intuition behind the true definition.

Comment: This topic has been discussed **at length** on this website. Please do your research before asking.

Comment: @K.defaoite I had searched on the site: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=what+is+tangent+to+any+curve%3F+ The most close question was this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591370/what-is-tangent-to-a-curve-or-function but none of the answer were rigours and satisfied me.

Comment: As @QiyuWen notes, that's not a definition, but an intuition. (Also, it's the etymology of the term "tangent" itself, which comes from the Latin *tangere*, "to touch".) *My* intuitionistic answer to the question "What is a tangent line?" is this: "The tangent at a point on a curve is the line that the curve *looks like* when you *zoom in* really-really-really close to that point." In your example, the green line is clearly not such a line; on the other hand, the red line actually appears to obscure the curve near the point in question, even at "low zoom", making it a good candidate.

Comment: As for why the (not-a-)definition is "so famous" ... Likely, it stems from the idea that tangents were (and still tend to be) first introduced in the context of circles, where "just touches" quite accurately and unambiguously captures the sense of things. It also conveys the right idea in the context of, say, conic sections. It's the *natural* descriptor to use for curves in general. However, with generality comes ambiguity and the potential for confusion (as in your objections), which is why we cannot (and *do* not) rely on "just touches" as a *definition*.

Comment: Come to think of it ... In the context of conic sections, "just touching" is more-or-less definitional for ellipses and hyperbolas, since a line can meet such a curve in one, two, or no points. But parabolas already highlight a need for caution, since there are two ways for a line to meet a parabola at a single point. Nowadays, we have the formality of Calculus (as well as a "projective" understanding of conics) to distinguish the tangent and non-tangent lines for the parabola. I'm kinda curious about how ancient mathematicians handled this nuance in the earliest treatises on conics.

Answer (score 1):

intuitively;  In the plane a line $ l $ is tangent to a curve $ c $ at point $ A $ if it is the only line that satisfies:

1. there is a region $ R $ of the plane such that $ l \cap c = \{A\} $ or $ A \in l \cap c $
2. $ l $ divides $ R $ into two regions $ R_1 $ and $ R_2 $ such that $ R_1 \cap c = \emptyset $ or $ R_2 \cap c = \emptyset $

Comment: What about the tangent in this image? https://images.app.goo.gl/ScmiAQ7Xdzm7XDoy7

Comment: @Zenra:  there is a region $R$ of the plane...

Comment: I don't understand what is $R$ here. Which region of plane?

Comment: @Zenra $R$ is a portion of the plane where $l$ satisfies 1 and 2. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1x3n76h3x76u18i/34%20sin%20t%C3%ADtulo_20200719063853.png?dl=0

Comment: @Zenra You can also define $R$ as a ball containing point $A$

Answer (score 0):

I think that the "just touches" means that "it doesn't go through". Maybe by looking to the contrapositive (the one I just mentioned) you will be "happier". And by the "just touches" in the sense that "it doesn't go through", a straight line tangent to another "just touches it". But yes, it is not the most rigorous approach and definitely not the one I would use, but it can be useful for the abstraction of this concept, if it satisfies you.

Comment: @it isn't satisfactory. Go to this site: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4pf1dxxzq2 Move the slider (below $a=-5.8$) and you will find that the tangent at lot many of point is crossing the curve and not just touching it.

Comment: I agree, it isn't satisfactory. But this approach is more applicable for people that aren't going to study rigorous mathematics, in my opinion. I wouldn't teach my students this way though...