# Differentiation. Why does differentiating a function allows us to find a tangent of a point of that specific function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know that the purpose of differentiation is to find the rate of change of a function. But i don't really understand how this is concept can be used to find the tangent of a specific point. It would be greatly appreciated if you can explain this to me.

Comment: Do you know the definition of derivative of a function $f$ at a point $x_0$? If so, that is the limit of the slope of a secant line joining the points $(x_0,f(x_0))$ and $(x_0+h,f(x_0+h))$ when $h$ tends to $0$. But then the secant line through the above two points tends to the tangent line at $(x_0,f(x_0))$.

Comment: See https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/acf917af6fb88659fe64f36e2b7c5d57_MIT18_01SCF10_Ses1b.pdf

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> One question to ask is, ["What by definition _is_ a tangent line?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495100/can-someone-provide-the-formal-definition-of-the-tangent-line-to-a-curve) If the definition is _the line whose slope at $(x_0, f(x_0))$ is $f'(x_0)$_, which is not unreasonable, there's not much to say. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one hand, differentiation has been indeed conceived as a measure of the variation of a given function $f(x)$, when on the other hand its geometric interpretation corresponds to the slope of the tangent line of the graph of the same function. Actually, the link between these two points of view lies in the fact that the tangent  slope is precisely the rate of change of $f(x)$, because the higher the slope (in absolute value), the bigger the variation of $f(x)$. This link is even "materialized" algebraically through the (first-order) Taylor expansion of $f(x)$, since $f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \mathcal{O}(x^2)$ coincides with the tangent line of $f(x)$ at $x = a$.